# Setting the Terminate and Unexpected Handler

Tags: c++, exception

Can you explain this:

> terminate_handler set_terminate (terminate_handler f) throw();

and this:

> unexpected_handler set_unexpected (unexpected_handler f) throw();

To change the terminate handler we have  use have to use the `set_terminate()`, shown above but i cant understand/interpret the above form. Can anyone explain that.

Also i am having trouble understanding this:

> terminate_handler set_terminate (terminate_handler f) throw();
>
> Here,
> f is a pointer to the new terminate handler.The function
> returns a pointer to the old terminate handler. The new terminate
> handler must be of type terminate_handler, which is defined like this:
>
> typedef void(*terminate_handler)();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`terminate_handler` is a typedef for a function pointer. When you set the terminate handler, you pass a pointer to the function that you want to be called on termination. That’s the argument to `set_terminate`. The function returns the old pointer. That way, if you just want to use your own terminate handler for a short period of time, you can restore the previous one when you’re done:

```
void my_terminator() {
    // whatever
}

int main() {
    // terminate here calls default handler

    terminate_handler old_handler = set_terminate(my_terminator);
    // now, terminate will call `my_terminator`

    set_terminate(old_handler);
    // now, terminate will call the default handler

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nicely explained , thankyou! I have one confusions              q1: Why is the 'throw()' keyword there, is it dynamic exception specification?

Comment: The `throw()`, because of the empty parentheses, says that the function does not throw any exceptions. These days it would be written as `noexcept`.

Comment: @ Pete Becker one last question so is `terminate_handler set_terminate (terminate_handler f) throw();` prototype for `set_terminate` function

Comment: @rimiro — yes, it’s a function prototype. Just like `int my_function(int i) throw();`. Just replace `int` with `terminate_handler`. Again, `terminate_handler` is a typedef name for a function pointer. That is, it’s the name of a type, much like `int`.